# Parametric equation, where parameter is prime

Tags: prime-numbers, parametric

$$6x^2-12x+3=p(x-2)$$ Where $p$ is a prime number. Find all parameters so that the equation has at least one integer root.
$$$$$$$$

$$6x(x-2)+3=p(x-2)$$ 
$$6x+\frac{3}{x-2}=p$$
$$3(2x+\frac{1}{x-2})=p$$
because of p is a prime number $$2x+\frac{1}{x-2}=1$$
$x=1$ and $p=3$
$$$$
However, I find that there is one more solution $x=5$ and $p=31$. But How?

Comment: In your second step you assumed that $x-2$ divides $2x(x-2)+1$ instead of the other factor, $3$. Keep your equation as $3(2x(x-2)+1)=p(x-2)$ and review the possible cases.

Comment: What you can do is to notice that $6x+\frac{3}{x-2}=p$ implies that $x-2$ divides $3$. This means that $x-2=\pm1$ or $\pm 3$.

Answer (score 0):

The step from $$3(2x+\frac{1}{x-2})=p$$

to  $$2x+\frac{1}{x-2}=1$$

gives us only one solution. If p must be an integer and prime, we must have that $x-2$ divides $3$, that is, $x$ divides $5$, so either $x=1$ and $p=3$, or $x=5$ and $p=31$. Note that we can't have $x<0$, for then we would have $p<0$ which can't be prime.

Comment: Actually, no so fast. There is also the case in which $x-2$ is multiple of $3$, and $(x-2)/3$ divides $2x(x-2)+1$ leaving a prime quotient.

Comment: If $x-2$ is a multiple of $3$, $x-2=3q$, then $3(2x+\frac{1}{x-2})=6x+\frac{1}{q}$ is not an integer if $q>1$.

Comment: Almost there. So, you need to look at the case $q\leq1$? $q=\pm1$ specifically.

Comment: $q$ is an integer. if $q=0$ then we have $x=2$ and $3=0$ in the original equation, which is a contradiction. If $q=1$ then $x=5$ which is one of the solutions I gave earlier. If $q=-1$, then $x=-1$ and $p<0$, so $p$ can't be prime.

Comment: $q$ can still be $-1$, which is the case you are missing to study. Look, I know how to solve this thing. I am just saying that your argument is incomplete. Complete it, such that you can understand it.